# Sorting a list of substrings by order they appear in original

Tags: java, substring, comparator

I have used a oomparator to sort an array by the length of the substrings. It works well, but is there a way to order the substrings of the same length in the array, ideally in the order they appear in the original string? For example if I sort the substrings of banana I get:
banana, anana, banan, bana, nana, anan... in this order and would like to get: banana, banan, anana, bana, anan, nana... which is the way they originally appear in banana.

How array is filled:

```
    public static String longestRepeated(String line) {
HashMap<String, Integer> subArray = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
String answer = "";
for (int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++) {
    for(int j = 1 ; j <= line.length() - i ; j++) {
        if (!subArray.containsKey(line.substring(i, i + j))) {
    subArray.put(line.substring(i, i + j), i);
    }
}
}
answer = subArray.keySet().toString();
answer = answer.replaceAll("\\[", "");
answer = answer.replaceAll("\\]", "");
String[] subs = answer.split(",");
LongestRepeatedSubstring lrs = new LongestRepeatedSubstring(line);
Arrays.sort(subs, lrs);
for (int i = 0 ; i < subs.length; i++) {
    subs[i] = subs[i].trim();
}
```

comparator:

```
    int lineLength;

public int compare(String str1, String str2) {
    int dist1 = Math.abs(str1.length() - lineLength);
    int dist2 = Math.abs(str2.length() - lineLength);
    return dist1 - dist2;
}
public LongestRepeatedSubstring(String line) {
    super();
    this.lineLength = line.length();
}
```

Then I use some loops to find the first one that is repeated and not at the same index. The issue occurs on cases where there are multiple repeated substrings in the array of the same length. I need the one the appears in the String first and they appear in the array randomly.

Comment: can you please make your question more readable? :) Can you show what you have done or any error you get?

Comment: Post your code, since it's not clear what array (if any) you have and how it was generated.

Comment: post up the error you get please?

Comment: In banana the longest repeated substrings are of length 2 and there are 2 "na" and "an". For some reason "na" is in the substring array before "an" and therefore gets returned, even though "an" appears first in "banana". This is the error.

Comment: Prefix each substring with it's offset in the original string, then sort.

Comment: Though why do you sort "bana" after "anana"?

Comment: Oh, you also want them by length.  Prefix with (total string length - substring length), then offset, then the string itself.  (Though the string itself is not needed for sorting, only for retrieving the value.)

Comment: "0.0.banana", "1.0.banan", "1.1.anana", "2.0.bana", "2.1.anan", "2.1.nana", "3.0.ban" ... etc  (You'd obviously need to expand the numeric fields for longer words, and always zero fill to the max field width.)

Comment: Hey Licks. If you want to put your last comment in an answer I'll accept it. Thanks for your help. Just added one more clause for if they are same size then sort by offset.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really get what you are asking but I think that what you are trying to say is that if there is a way to campare again inside the comparator. Right? If that is the case here is an example:

```
public static Comparator<String> CompareBySomeRestrictionAndOtherRestriction = new Comparator<String>(){
    public int compare(String s, String p){
         if(){//first condition, for example some strings are the same size
              //then use some other criteria, for example alphabetical order
         }else{

         }   
    }

}
```

You just have to work your way in how you are managing the comparisons in order to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you do not need a comparator: just print all the substrings